# Behavior of the single-threaded default scheduler used with Spring @Scheduled/@EnableScheduling registrar when a TaskScheduler is not setup/available

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, scheduledexecutorservice

As noted in the Spring docs for [EnableScheduling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html), when a TaskScheduler pool is not setup/available/resolvable, "*a local single-threaded default scheduler will be created and used within the registrar*"

Now when this happens what is the nature & behavior of this default scheduler particularly w.r.t whether or not its thread would potentially get terminated due to a failure during execution that is not caught/handled?

Is this default scheduler an instance of [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.html)? If so then what is its default [ErrorHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ErrorHandler.html) strategy ? Is it that the throwable is simply logged?

Or is this default scheduler a simpler one, simply an instance of [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) that is constructed from invoking [Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()) where in as stated there, "*if this single thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks*".

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answers myself after looking at the Spring task scheduling source code. Sharing here for others.

For this one,

> Now when this happens what is the nature & behavior of this default scheduler particularly w.r.t whether or not its thread would potentially get terminated due to a failure during execution that is not caught/handled?

Answer is as expected, it won't. User submitted tasks are decorated as a `org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable` that wraps the user Runnable, catches any exception or error thrown from it and allows an `org.springframework.util.ErrorHandler` to handle it. Here is the [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/84fd94271251c14fc74a1b7fa595f793d79cf9ca/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/support/DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java#L32).

For this one,

> Is this default scheduler an instance of ThreadPoolTaskScheduler? If so then what is its default ErrorHandler strategy ? Is it that the throwable is simply logged?

> Or is this default scheduler a simpler one, simply an instance of
> ScheduledExecutorService that is constructed from invoking
> Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()...

Answer is its an instance of `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrentConcurrentTaskScheduler` that does wrap a ScheduledExecutorService constructed from invoking [Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()).

The [ErrorHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ErrorHandler.html) strategy is to log the user Throwables at error level. In addition, repeated tasks will also have the user Throwable suppressed & not propagated (so that subsequent executions of the task will not be prevented) while for one shot tasks it will be propagated (re-thrown) as expected. Here is the [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/84fd94271251c14fc74a1b7fa595f793d79cf9ca/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/config/ScheduledTaskRegistrar.java#L378).

Both of the above is what i was expecting, but wanted to make sure since the nature & behavior of this default is not clearly documented. Perhaps a little more documentation might help.

Thanks